# How to access next sibling within a sorted for loop in XSLT 1.x?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this input XML:

```
<projects>
    <project>
        <number>1</number>
        <title>Project X</title>
    </project>
    <project>
        <number>unknown</number>
        <title>Project Y</title>
    </project>
    <project>
        <number>2</number>
        <title>Project Z</title>
    </project>
</projects>
```

The XSL loops over all project items in a sorted manner and I want to to something if the next sibling project contains the number `unknown`...

How do I do that?

This does not work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/projects/project">
  <xsl:sort select="./title"/>
  <xsl:if test="./following-sibling::*[1]/number = 'unknown'">
    ...
  </xs:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Minimal but complete samples together with an exact description of the error you get or the wrong output you get and the one you want are needed to allow us to understand the problem. Using prefixes in XPath expressions without showing the exact namespace declarations in both XML and XSLT is rather pointless.

Comment: it's the default namespace. Maybe I found the solution myself and will post it soon.

Comment: The next sibling in input order or after sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to this problem: when you sort the elements within a loop, you can not use sibling functions because the underlying nodelist is still unsorted, so you access wrong nodes.

The solution is to first sort the nodes and then do the sibling-function.

```
<xsl:variable name="sorted">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*/projects/project">
    <xsl:sort select="./title"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="node-set($sorted)/*">
  <xsl:if test="./following-sibling::*[1]/number = 'unknown'">
    ...
  </xs:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Please note that `node-set` is a function of http://exslt.org/common which you have to import in your XSL.